# How to prevent jQuery .remove() from deleting parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created an clone element function which can be viewed [view demo here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/store/app). When the reset button is pressed it removes all cloned item elements, however when attempting to add another item the item list, the 'NEW' added item are not visible with the DOM.

```
 $('#add-btn').on('click',function(){
    $('.list-items:first').clone().appendTo("#items").addClass('isVisible');
    $('#items-fields').val('');
})

// RESET BUTTON 
$('.reset').on('click', function(){
    if( $('.list-items').length != 1);
    $('.list-items:last').remove();
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: You need to specify which item you want to remove. When you do that using a class name all the elements with this class will be affected. If you want to be sure to get help post please all the relevant code, so it is possible to emulate the behavior.

Comment: @Franco unless i have written my question poorly, it's quite self explanatory.. the elements I want to remove are '.list-items' which are demonstrated in the demo and is written in the code. (THEY ARE BEING REMOVED WITH THE CURRENT FUNCTION). if you view the demo you'll notice when the user presses the reset button all items are removed, when you try to add new items they are not visible on the DOM, again written in the question and is demonstrated in the demo

Comment: I saw that, and I also saw that you have posted an other question before this one. As you can see, you didn't get much response for the fist one and you can of course do what you wish. I was just giving you an advise to raise your chance on a good answer for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have your reset button change the code in your if statement to the following

```
$('.reset').on('click', function(){
    if($('.list-items').length > 1) {
        $('.list-items:last').remove();
    }
})
```

At the moment you have set your list-items the following way..

```
When a user clicks the delete button, if the number of  things with the class list-item does not equal 0, then remove the last list-item
```

You need to change it the code so it does the following:

```
When a user clicks the delete button, if the number of  things with the class list-item is greater than 1, then remove the last list-item
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this:

```
var eleClone = $('list-items').clone(true);
```

by this:

```
var eleClone = $('.list-items').clone(true);
```

You search for the element which 'id' is 'list-item' while you want to search for the element which class is 'list-items'.

Comment: I have tried this but is doesn't remove cloned elements

Comment: sure, that command will replace every list item by the eleClone content.